# Excel VBA, suddenly can't find path?

Tags: file, path

I got this:
"vba runtime error, cannot save the attachment. path does not exist. verify the path is correct"

I use this:

```
Sub Save_Outlook_Attachements_Calls()

Dim ol As Outlook.Application
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim callfol As Outlook.Folder
Dim salefol As Outlook.Folder
Dim i As Object
Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
Dim at As Outlook.Attachment
Dim fPat As String
fPat = ThisWorkbook.Path



Set ol = New Outlook.Application
Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")



Set callfol = ns.Folders("xxx.xxx@xxx.com").Folders("OutlookData").Folders("Calls")
    

For Each i In callfol.Items
    If i.Class = olMail Then
    
        Set mi = i
        
            
            If mi.Attachments.Count > 0 And Format(mi.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd") = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") Then
                             
                       For Each at In mi.Attachments
                                                  
                        '------------ ------------
                       at.SaveAsFile (fPat & "\Outlookdata\calls\" & Date & "." & FSO.GetExtensionName(fPat & "\Outlookdata\calls\" & at.Filename))
                                    
                Next at
                
            End If
    End If
    
Next i
End Sub
```

It's the Row in the end that gets the error message:
Starting with "at.SaveAsFile (fPat &"
I have checked what the variabel "Fpat" contains, and its "H:\VBA"
So its like it always has been, and the server still called H:

All of that has been working perfect, but suddenly it doesn't?
Its a server map, but i can reach it in the file explorer like normal.
I have restarted the pc :) but error persists.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, i had changed the windows system language to English last week, not just the programs, in which already is in english.
That made the date variable im using to the format 2022/06/20, ie: "/" and that cannot be used in a file name..
i never thought i would find it by my self :)